# Batch gradient descent for linear regression , but the dimensions of output is not as same as initialized

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, gradient-descent

This is the code I tried to minimize the value of theta ,but the dimension of theta is not the same as initialized .

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import add_dummy_feature
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
X, y = load_diabetes(return_X_y=True)

Xtr, Xte, ytr, yte = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=2)

Xnu = add_dummy_feature(Xtr)
Xtest1 = add_dummy_feature(Xte)


theta = np.random.randn(11, 1)
multi = np.dot(Xnu, theta)
mrav = multi
sub = mrav - ytr
dot = Xnu.T@(sub)

eta = 0.1  # learning rate
n_epochs = 1000
m = len(Xnu)  # number of instances

np.random.seed(42)
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    gradients = 2 / m * dot
    theta = theta - eta * gradients
```